# Using trapezoidal rule to approximate an integral

Tags: matlab, numeric

I'm trying to use trapezoidal method in Matlab to have relative error 1%. Here is my code:

```
a=0;b=2;

N=0;k=0;

it=0;is=0;

function y=g(x)

       d=1+x^3+x^4;

       y=x^2*d;

end

sumtn=0.5*(g(a)+g(b));sumt2n=sumtn;

while 1

        k=k+1;%Number of times I split the distance [a,b] in 
        equal parts

        N=2^k;%Number of parts that the distance is being 
        split for every iteration

        h=(b-a)/N;

        for i=1:N-1

                  xi=a+i*h;

                 xi2n=xi-h/2;%for 2*N parts

                 sumtn=sumtn+g(xi);

                 sumt2n=sumt2n+g(xi2n)+g(xi);

        end

       It2n=sumt2n*h/2;

       Itn=sumtn*h;

       Et=abs(It2n-Itn)/3;

       if Et/It2n<=0.01

                break;
      end
end
```

The result turns out to be approximately twice as big as the expected value so I think I'm missing something.

Comment: trapz computes integral approximations by trapezoid rule.

Comment: Please format your code properly. You can select all code and press the `{}` button on the editor toolbar. This will indent it 4 spaces, which indicates to the renderer that it is code. It will make it a lot easier for us to read. Then you can also indent your loops etc.

Comment: I know there is the function trapz but i am trying to do it myself.Thanks i will try to fix the code